# Highlight matches of search word(s) within a target string of word(s)

Tags: javascript, html, regex, search, full-text-search

*Task:* Given a search term consisting of one or more words, highlight each of the words found within target string of one or more words. Note that the search words can appear in any order, and should match even if not all of the words are found within the target string.

*Reason:* To help the user visualise why the target string was matched against the search term by highlighting the matches.

*Requirement:* I also want this to match case insensitive.

##### It should handle simple cases

*Needles:* `Foo bar`
*Hay:* `I pity the fool`
*Desired result:* I pity the **foo**l

##### It should match multiple search words split by string, in any order in the target string

*Needles:* `Foo bar`
*Hay:* `I pity the bar fool`
*Desired result:* I pity the **bar** **foo**l

##### It should handle instances where the search terms may conflict with each other

*Needles:* `Barbeque bar`
*Hay:* `Quality barbeque grill`
*Desired result:* Quality **barbeque** grill

Answer (score 0):

My solution here is based upon:

1. Splitting the search term into the search words.
2. One by one going through the target string to see if the search word exists within the target string. This is done by splitting on the search word.

   - Those with an odd index will be the word(s) to highlight (if no match was found the result will have a length of `1` and that item will have an index of `0`).
3. Feeding back the results into step 2, but only trying to highlight within the target string the parts that aren't already highlighted.

Personally I'm then using the output array directly with Vue, and letting that handle the templating tasks, but have included an example here of how it can output simple HTML to be rendered.

```html
<script lang="js">
  const splitHighlight = (arrayOfStrings, highlightWord) => {
    // use () for capture and keeping the matched string, and `i` for case
    // insensitive matching
    const regex = new RegExp(`(${highlightWord})`, "i");
    return arrayOfStrings
      .map((s, i) => {
        // if the index is odd then then this string is already highlighted,
        // so don't try to highlight within the highlight
        const isAlreadyHighlighted = i % 2 !== 0;
        return isAlreadyHighlighted ? [s] : s.split(regex);
      })
      .flat();
  };

  const splitNeedlesInHay = (needlesStr, hay) => {
    const needlesArray = needlesStr.trim().split(" ");
    let hayArray = [hay];
    needlesArray.forEach((n) => (hayArray = splitHighlight(hayArray, n)));
    return hayArray;
  };

  const highlightNeedlesInHay = (needlesStr, hay) => {
    const needlesInHay = splitNeedlesInHay(needlesStr, hay);
    console.log(needlesInHay);

    const transformHayArrayToHtmlReducer = (acc, curr, index) => {
      return acc + (index % 2 === 0 ? curr : `<b>${curr}</b>`);
    };

    return needlesInHay.reduce(transformHayArrayToHtmlReducer);
  };
  
  const result1 = highlightNeedlesInHay("Foo bar", "I pit the fool");
  console.log(result1);
  document.write(result1 + "<br />");
  
  const result2 = highlightNeedlesInHay("Foo bar", "I pit the bar fool");
  console.log(result2);
  document.write(result2 + "<br />");
  
  const result3 = highlightNeedlesInHay("Barbeque bar", "Quality barbeque grill");
  console.log(result3);
  document.write(result3 + "<br />");
</script>
```